# Necesito pasarle dinamicamente al objeto "query" de SQLAlchemy los parametros de la clase junto a sus atributos

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

Necesito armar dinamicamente la parte en la que el `.query()` obtiene la clase de los objetos y sus atributos, es decir, que dentro de `query` se inserte dinámicamente las tablas y columnas que reciba desde otra aplicación. Por ejemplo:

```
session.query(CcSipUser.id).all()
```

Me retorna de la tabla "CcSipUser" la columna "id", si quiero otros objetos hago lo siguiente `session.query(CcSipUser.id, CcSipUser.name).all()`.

Pero necesito armar el script dependiendo de los valores que me pasen, si con esa misma tabla quieren "name", "id" u otra columna de la tabla.

Estoy usuando esta forma también para transformar los valores que me pasan a un objeto con su atributo.

```
columnasid = getattr(CcSipUser, "id")
columnasusr = getattr(CcSipUser, "username")
session.query(columnasusr, columnasid).all()
```

Equivale a lo que escribí anteriormente pero, ¿cómo podría insertarlos entre los paréntesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no mal entiendo, lo que quieres es seleccionar dinámicamente las columnas al generar la consulta SQL.

Lo que puedes hacer es inspeccionar el modelo (clase SQLAlchemy) y obtener una lista de las propidades (referencias) que deseas pasar como parametro al metodo `query` de SQLAlchemy.

La función:

```
def column_selector(model, props):
    columns = []
    for prop in props:
        if hasattr(model, prop):
            columns.append(getattr(model, prop))

    return columns
```

Luego dicha lista, lo pasas al metodo `query()` agregado el prefijo asterisco (*), por ejemplo, `session.query(*argument).all()`. El asterisco "*" se utiliza en Python para definir un número variable de argumentos

Un ejemplo de como usarlo:

```
class Entity(database.Model):

    id = database.Column(database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = database.Column(database.String)
    lastname = database.Column(database.String)
    age = database.Column(database.Integer)
    gender = database.Column(database.Integer)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    # creamos a lista de columnas (sus nombres) que queremos de una
    # tabla determinada.
    props = ['name', 'gender']


    # pasamos la lista a la funcion
    columns = column_selector(Entity, props)

    # y pasamos la lista de columnas con el prefijo *
    database.session.query(*columns).all()

    # mas codigo ...

    return ':)'
```

La linea `database.session.query(*columns).all()` pasa a equivaler a:

```
database.session.query(Person.name, Person.gender).all()
```

## Notas

- Yo he utilizado [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) para la integracion entre Flask y SQLAlchemy, pero la implementacion es la misma.
- Puedes ver el codigo SQL generado en la consola conifgurando al propiedad `echo` a `True` del objeto engine.

de forma directa:

```
engine.echo = True
```

Si utilizas Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```